# Проблемы с X11 over SSH

Tags: x11, ssh, linux

Добрый день, на одной из машин непонятные проблемы:

```
$ ssh -XY localhost xclockX11 forwarding request failed on channel 0Error: Can't open display: $$ xhost +access control disabled, clients can connect from any host$$ ssh -XY localhost xclockX11 forwarding request failed on channel 0Error: Can't open display: $$ xauth listhost/unix:0  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  b03f4200000b6f165b48e37321f9c606localhost.localdomain/unix:0  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  b03f4200000b6f165b48e37321f9c606host.domain.tld:0  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  b03f4200000b6f165b48e37321f9c606host.domain.tld:0  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  b03f4200000b6f165b48e37321f9c606host.domain.tld:0  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  b03f4200000b6f165b48e37321f9c606localhost:0  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  b03f4200000b6f165b48e37321f9c606$ _
```

Даже не знаю куда смотреть

Comment: А по ssh (в консоли) на ту машину нормально коннектит?

Comment: Да, проблемы именно с X11

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена, это были какие-то странности в районе IPv6 файрвола